# How to create VMware-ESXi bootable USB in Linux

Tags: boot, usb, vmware, iso-image

How to create VMware-ESXi bootable USB **in Linux** using the `VMware-VMvisor-Installer-7.0U3-18644231.x86_64.iso` ?

Simply dd-ing the iso don't work {usb doesn't show up in boot menu} and web suggests to use `Rufus` which isn't a linux application.Also tried booting uing refind but no success

PC is UEFI-capable and win isn't installed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried making bootable using [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)?

Comment: @Jhon thanks for the reply ; UNetbootin did work and i installed it successfully but now the drive on which i installed is itself not showing up in boot menu ; can you help me with that ?